# TaskCompletionSource - Trying to understand threadless async work

Tags: asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to understand the purpose of `TaskCompletionSource` and its relation to async/threadless work. I think I have the general idea but I want to make sure my understanding is correct.

I first started looking into the Task Parallel Library (TPL) to figure out if there was a good way to create your own threadless/async work (say you're trying to improve scalability of your ASP.NET site) plus understanding of the TPL looks like it will be very important in the future (`async`/`await`). Which led me to the `TaskCompletionSource`.

From my understanding it looks like adding `TaskCompletionSource` to a one of your classes doesn't really do much in as making your coding async; if you're still executing sync code then the call to your code will block. I think this is even true of microsoft APIs. For example, say in `DownloadStringTaskAsync` off of `WebClient` class, any setup / sync code they are doing initially will block. The code you're executing has to run on some thread, either the current thread or you will have to spin off a new one.

So you use `TaskCompletionSource` in your own code when you're calling other `async` calls from Microsoft so the client of your classes doesn't have to create a new thread for your class to not block.

Not sure how Microsoft does their async APIs internally. For example, there is a new `async` method off of the `SqlDataReader` for .Net 4.5. I know there is IO Completion Ports. I think it's a lower level abstraction (C++?) that probably most C# developers won't use. Not sure if IO completion Ports will work for Database or network calls (HTTP) or if its just used for file IO.

So the question is, am I correct in my understanding correct? Are there certain things I've represented incorrectly?

Comment: If my understanding is correct...not sure if it is or not

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`TaskCompletionSource` is used to create `Task` objects that don't execute code.

They're used quite a bit by Microsoft's new async APIs - any time there's I/O-based asynchronous operations (or other non-CPU-based asynchronous operations, like a timeout). Also, any `async Task` method you write will use TCS to complete its returned `Task`.

I have a blog post [Creating Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/creating-tasks.html) that discusses different ways to create `Task` instances. It's written from an `async`/`await` perspective (not a TPL perspective), but it still applies here.

Also see Stephen Toub's excellent posts:

- [The Nature of TaskCompletionSource](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/the-nature-of-taskcompletionsourcetresult/)
- [Mechanisms for Creating Tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/mechanisms-for-creating-tasks/)
- [await anything;](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/) (using `TaskCompletionSource` to `await` anything).
- [Using Tasks to implement the APM Pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/using-tasks-to-implement-the-apm-pattern/) (creating `Begin`/`End` using `TaskCompletionSource`).

Comment: Thanks Stephen but is my understanding on the internals correct?

Comment: Any asynchronous method does (of course) have a synchronous portion that is used to start the asynchronous operation. IIRC, IOCPs can be used for any kind of `HANDLE`-based data transfer, and it's not uncommon (today) to have an IOCP operation wrapped in a `Begin`/`End` wrapped in an `async` method that wraps it in a `Task` (using `TaskCompletionSource`).

Comment: I also am trying to understand the usage of TaskCompletionSource, and I'm a bit confused as to why you would have a task that doesn't execute code. I read your blog post; it seems that TCS is used as an event that a caller can subscribe to, but why would you want to do that when you can use a regular Task and wait on the Task till it completes?

Comment: `TaskCompletionSource` is logically more of an event *handler*, and *produces* a `Task` that other code can `await`. There are two kinds of tasks: Delegate Tasks and Promise Tasks; I have [a blog post that explains some of the differences](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html).

Answer (score 8):

I like the explanation which was provided in http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/TaskCompletionSource

(sorry, the link may be dead at the moment)

First two paragraphs are below

> We've seen how Task.Run creates a task that runs a delegate on a
>   pooled (or non-pooled) thread. Another way to create a task is with
>   TaskCompletionSource.
>
> TaskCompletionSource lets you create a task out of any operation that
>   starts and finishes some time later. It works by giving you a "slave"
>   task that you manually drive—by indicating when the operation finishes
>   or faults. This is ideal for I/O- bound work: you get all the benefits
>   of tasks (with their ability to propagate return values, exceptions,
>   and continuations) without blocking a thread for the duration of the
>   operation.
>
> To use TaskCompletionSource, you simply instantiate the class. It
>   exposes a Task property that returns a task upon which you can wait
>   and attach continuations—just as with any other task. The task,
>   however, is controlled entirely by the TaskCompletionSource object via
>   the following methods:

```
public class TaskCompletionSource<TResult> 
{ 
 public void SetResult(TResult result); 
 public void SetException (Exception exception); 

 public void SetCanceled();   
 public bool TrySetResult (TResult result); 
 public bool TrySetException (Exception exception); 
 public bool TrySetCanceled();
 ... 
}
```

> Calling any of these methods signals the task, putting it into a
>   completed, faulted, or canceled state (we'l cover the latter in the
>   section "Cancellation"). You'e supposed to call one of these methods
>   exactly once: if called again, SetResult, SetException, or SetCanceled
>   will throw an exception, whereas the Try* methods return false.
>
> The following example prints 42 after waiting for five seconds:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
new Thread (() =>     {
                       Thread.Sleep (5000); 
                       tcs.SetResult (42); 
                      })    
           .Start();   
Task<int> task = tcs.Task;    // Our "slave" task. 
Console.WriteLine(task.Result);  // 42
```

Other interesting quotes

> The real power of TaskCompletionSource is in creating tasks that don't
>   tie up threads.

.. and later on

> Our use of TaskCompletionSource without a thread means that a thread
>   is engaged only when the continuation starts, five seconds later. We
>   can demonstrate this by starting 10,000 of these operations at once
>   without error or excessive resource consumption: