# Rewriting code to take advantage of C# async feature

Tags: c#, async-await

How to transform such code:

```
public void Do2()
{
        Console.WriteLine("Do2::Before");
        Latent(() => Console.WriteLine("Do2::After"));
}
public void Latent(Action a)
{
     registeredActions.Add(a);
}
public void TriggerActions()
{
        foreach (Action a in registeredActions)
        {
            a();
        }
}
```

To be usable like this:

```
public async void Do1()
{
        Console.WriteLine("Do1::Before");
        await Latent();
        Console.WriteLine("Do1::After");
}
```

Note that I do not want Tasks to be executed on ThreadPool or on other threads or magically behind my back, just when I want them to, i.e. decide by myself when Task is "completed" and call whatever code is after *await Latent()*, most likely in the same thread as Do1 is called. Sample usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("Before Do");
ts.Do2();
Console.WriteLine("After Do, before triggering actions");
// ... do some other stuff and when it is the right time to "complete pending tasks"
ts.TriggerActions();
Console.WriteLine("After triggering actions");
```

I couldn't find any solution for this, all C# async samples talk about await client.GetStringAsync(.. or Thread.Sleep(... or Task.Delay(...

Comment: You might be able to just use a custom task scheduler if the threading behavior is the only issue you have with Task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
Task Latent()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

  ... // Apply some logic here to eventually call "tcs.TrySetResult".

  return tcs.Task;
}
```

This can be used as such:

```
public async Task Do1()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Do1::Before");
  await Latent();
  Console.WriteLine("Do1::After");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great & simple solution. However, it is worth checking also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419747/taskcompletionsource-trying-to-understand-threadless-async-work)